# split string to some parts and replace a one sub-string with another string

Tags: arrays, string, perl, substring

I am trying to replace a string with a substring which is located in between other two parts.

To describe, I have a file which contains some text in. In this text file there is one word which some parts of it are written in different character, as an example like:

```
acc\E34rate
acc\?4rate
acc§54rate
.....
```

What I want to write as a code is, to lookup for for `acc` and then `rate` and then replace what is between them with `u`. Because all strings are in commen with the the first part and the last part.

I wonder how I can do it in Perl?

Thanks!

**Update: including Code**

well what I have written is:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @stringArray  = ('acc\E34rate', 'acc\?4rate');
my $find    = '\E34';
my $replace = 'u';  
my @newArray;

    foreach my $str(@stringArray)
    {
        my $pos = index($str, $find);

        while($pos > -1) {
            substr($str, $pos, length($find), $replace);
            $pos = index($str, $find, $pos + length($replace));
        }

        push @newSrray, $str;
    }

    foreach(@newArray)
    {
        print "$_\r\n";
    }
```

To simplify, I have added an array instead of a file. Because it works for only a proper word rather than the whole array/file.

Comment: "which some parts of it are written in different character" is not a well specified splitting criterion...

Comment: @timgeb well, I had only this idea. If you have better idea Please write it as answer! :)

Comment: @Royeh: Errm, that's not how it works. Programming starts with outlining your functional requirements as clear as possible... Also, you appear to have forgotten to paste your code. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @L.O.vanIngen you can  find now my update to the question and code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want but the requirements are not clear. See [`perldoc perlre`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) for more details.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $begin   = 'acc';
my $end     = 'rate';
my $replace = 'u';

while( my $line = <DATA> ){
    $line =~ s{ \Q$begin\E \S*? \Q$end\E }{$begin$replace$end}gmsx;
    print $line;
}

__DATA__
acc\E34rate
acc\?4rate
acc§54rate
acc\E34rate acc\?4rate acc§54rate
accFOOacc
rateFOOrate
rateFOOrate accFOOacc
accFOOacc rateFOOrate
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$Text = "acc\E34rate
acc\?4rate
acc§54rate"; # This is the joined string (using enter key) after reading from the file
$Text =~ s/^acc.*?rate$/accutext/mg;
print $Text;
```

I've just tested it in my system and it is working fine.

Output:

> accutext
>   accutext
>   accutext

`m` is to denote that the string is a multi line string and that each `\n` will be treated as an end of string character.

`g` is to replace all possible occurrences.

To get back as an array, split using `\n`.

Please note that the above code is written based on the assumption that each line in the file will begin and end with acc and text respectively and that there are no additional text after or before them in that line (ie, File is not having individual lines like `"Driving acc\?4rate at 60kmph" and only "acc\?4rate"`).
In case this word is in between words in a sentence, replace below in the above code.

```
$Text =~ s/acc.*?rate/accutext/g;
```

Incidentally, this will work in all possible inputs too, including the code at the top.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? My answer matches the question asked perfectly!